# android API27 not detecting external usb camera ( LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL)

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying list number of cameras (Front, back, external) using API27 (8.1.0) (which they claim as supporting external USB camera.) But couldn't. 
Looks like android api (camera2) doesn't support this, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Android camera API supports external camera but it still needs device manufacturers to implement this feature at kernerl/HAL level. My understanding is not too many devices today actually implements this feature.

Comment: is there a way to find a device that has it implemented? Other than by brute force (i.e. purchasing devices and trying them out).

Comment: There isn't a list available to my knowledge. The guaranteed way to get this support is probably build your own system image/kernel on devices supports that.   You can find more information here: https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras

Comment: thanks for the tip, but what do you mean by "on devices supports that"? Support what, flushing your own kernel? I though all of them support that if you unlock the bootloader. Or do you mean something else?